# Maven GAE Plugin - Change account to deploy to

Tags: google-app-engine, maven

I have created an google app engine project and wanted to deploy it via

```
mvn appengine:update
```

the browser window openend and I  was asked for oauth permission by google, I then copied the key / code and pasted it in the console, just when I realised that I was logged in with the wrong google account.

so my question is: **how do I reset the authentication to deploy it to a different account?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution by just carefully reading the Documentation on https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven .

On a Mac at least, you have to rename or delete the **.appcfg_oauth2_tokens_java** file in you home directory, so that the next time you try to deploy it, it will ask again for authentication.